# Convert java object in JSON

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert a simple java object in JSON. I'm using google Gson library and it works, but I want a complete JSON object in this form:

```
{"Studente":[{ "nome":"John", "cognome":"Doe","matricola":"0512","dataNascita":"14/10/1991"}]}
```

This is my class:

```
public class Studente {

    private String nome;
    private String cognome;
    private String matricola;
    private String dataNascita;

    public Studente(){

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public String getMatricola() {
        return matricola;
    }

    public void setMatricola(String matricola) {
        this.matricola = matricola;
    }

    public String getDataNascita() {
        return dataNascita;
    }

    public void setDataNascita(String dataNascita) {
        this.dataNascita = dataNascita;
    }

}
```

This is tester:

```
Studente x = new Studente();
x.setCognome("Doe");
x.setNome("Jhon");
x.setMatricola("0512");
x.setDataNascita("14/10/1991");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String toJson = gson.toJson(x, Studente.class);
System.out.println("ToJSON "+toJson);
```

I have this in toJson: `{"nome":"Jhon","cognome":"Doe","matricola":"0512","dataNascita":"14/10/1991"}`

Comment: why do you think that is a complete JSON object?

Comment: i need also the name of the class in json string

Comment: @JunbangHuang not work, there isn't studente in json: [{"nome":"Jhon","cognome":"Doe","matricola":"0512","dataNascita":"14/10/1991"}]

Comment: sorry, not list, but a map. put `x` into a map, the key is "Student" and the value is a list contains x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to write a wrapper for Students list. like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudentWrapper {
  private ArrayList<Studente> studente;

  public StudentWrapper() {
    studente = new ArrayList<Studente>();
  }

  public void addStudent(Studente s){
    studente.add(s);
  }
}
```

Code to convert to JSON :

```
Studente x=new Studente();
x.setCognome("Doe");
x.setNome("Jhon");
x.setMatricola("0512");
x.setDataNascita("14/10/1991");
Gson gson=new Gson();
StudentWrapper studentWrapper = new StudentWrapper();
studentWrapper.addStudent(x);
String toJson=gson.toJson(studentWrapper, StudentWrapper.class);
System.out.println("ToJSON "+toJson);
```

The output will be like this. The way you want it.

```
ToJSON {"studente":[{"nome":"Jhon","cognome":"Doe","matricola":"0512","dataNascita":"14/10/1991"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Json that you are trying to achieve is not the representation of a single Studente object, it is the representation of an object containing a list of Studente objects, that has a single entry.

So, you would need to create that extra object that contains the list of Studente objects, add the one instance to the list, and then serialize the object containing the list.

There's one minor issue, though. You are essentially asking for the wrapper object's list to have a property name that starts with a capital letter. This can be done, but breaks Java coding conventions.